# Call a ASP.NET script from a C# desktop app

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-scraping

I'm trying to develop a desktop app to be used as a website scraping tool. My requirement is the user should be able to specify a url in the desktop app.The desktop app should be able to invoke the asp.net script to scrape data from the website and return the records to the desktop app.

Should I use a web service or a ASP.NET runtime for this...???

Any help is appreciated :)

**Additional details**

The scraping activity is already done.I used HTMLAgility pkg. This is my scraping code to extract a list of company names from a web page.

```
public static String getPageHTML(String URL)
        {
            String totalCompanies = null;
            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(URL);

            IWebProxy myProxy = httpWebRequest.Proxy;

            if (myProxy != null)
            {
                myProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            }

            httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

            HttpWebResponse res;

            res = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();

            HtmlDocument doc1 = new HtmlDocument();

            doc1.Load(res.GetResponseStream());

            HtmlNode node = doc1.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//td[@class='mainbody']/table/tr[last()]/td");

            try
            {
                totalCompanies = node.InnerText;
                return totalCompanies;
            }
            catch (NullReferenceException e)
            {
                   totalCompanies = "No records found";
                    return totalCompanies;

             }




        }
```

Comment: I think you need web service.

Comment: Why cant you just download through WebClient? and use HtmlAgilityPack to parse retrieved html? Also, look into some basics of multithreading to do things in parallel.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) within your desktop app, i've done this before (winforms). For example: -

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("url");
var response = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

You can then use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to parse the data from the response:

```
 HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(response);

 //Sample query
 var node = doc.DocumentNode.Descendants("div")
           .Where(d => d.Attributes.Contains("id")).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks DGibbs.I'll try this and come back to you :)

Answer (score 0):

(it would be helpful to include more details/be more specific)

If your ASP.NET page already does all the scraping, and all you need to do is access that ASP.NET page, you can simply use HttpWebRequest

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/456dfw4f.aspx - short description & tutorial

If that URL is the website TO BE SCRAPED, and you need to include that ASP.NET script in your project, then you need to add it as a web service.

Comment: the URL is the website to be scraped

Comment: Ok. And where is the ASP.NET script you want to use? you either have to reference it in your code, or (wild guess) HTTP send it your url as a parameter. 

Please provide more details about the script

Comment: ok..now I don't really understand where's the problem. You've got the code to scrape, you've got the desktop app..what's the issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with both but also you can do it by adding a webbrowser to your desktop application. I don't know why but result is much more faster.